# Linux scheduling policy: SCHED_FIFO against SCHED_RR

Tags: linux, scheduled-tasks

from what I have understood during my search, a FIFO task needs to either block or voluntarily yield, in order to release the CPU and allow others to run on that CPU. What I can't be sure about is 3 specific cases:

1) Would a (runnable) FIFO task with prio 99 ever preempt a (running) FIFO task with prio 90?

*I believe the answer is NO, please comment*

2) Would a (runnable) FIFO task with prio 50 preempt a (running) RR task with prio 99(before the RR timeslice is over) ?

*I believe the answer is YES, please comment*

3) Would a (runnable) RR task with prio 99 ever preempt a (running) FIFO task of prio 50?

*I believe the answer is NO, please comment*

Assume a latest Linux RedHat kernel.

Thank you

Alex

Comment: Why not just try these and see?

Comment: Hi, well believe me I thought of this, not just now, but for various issues in the past. Sometimes, you need to know very well what you are testing, in order to test it right, and extract the right conclusions. I am looking for answers that respond to the theory, and are based on experience, and knowledge for this specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

In linux SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_RR share real time priorites which goes from 0 to 99 (99 being the highest) at least in userspace. From now on i am assuming you are talking about these priorities (rt_priority) instead the internal prio field. Given this information here how your scenario *should* work:

1. Since 99 is higher it will preempt the FIFO task of task 90, unless preemption is disabled by that task.
2. No, since priority 50 is less it should not be able to preempt task of priority 99.
3. Yes again the priority 99 is higher so it should preempt task of priority 50.

Lastly if you are confused between prio and rt_prio here is the relation between them, it can be found in function normal_prio

```
/*
 * Calculate the expected normal priority: i.e. priority
 * without taking RT-inheritance into account. Might be
 * boosted by interactivity modifiers. Changes upon fork,
 * setprio syscalls, and whenever the interactivity
 * estimator recalculates.
 */
static inline int normal_prio(struct task_struct *p)
{
    int prio;

    if (task_has_dl_policy(p))
            prio = MAX_DL_PRIO-1;
    else if (task_has_rt_policy(p))
            prio = MAX_RT_PRIO-1 - p->rt_priority; // This is for FIFO/RR Tasks
    else
            prio = __normal_prio(p);
    return prio;
}
```